# How is ($\mathbb{Z}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$) a subset of $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, integers, rational-numbers, natural-numbers

I do not understand why the set ($\mathbb{Z}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$) is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. $\mathbb{Q}$ extends the $\mathbb{Z}$ by adding fractions. So there cannot be an element in $\mathbb{Z}$ which is not in $\mathbb{Q}$. Where am I going wrong with my thoughts?

Comment: $\emptyset \subset \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, then remove elements of $\mathbb{Q}$. What's left?  Nothing.  And for sure, $\varnothing$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.  Along the same lines, $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is a subset of the set of all pieces of furniture in my house.  (For this, you must be okay with the fact that the empty set is a subset of every set.)

Comment: There is my next question. Another example which should be true: N\Z = ∅. By definition the empty set is a subset of every set. So the empty set is element of N and of Z, so the proposition actually should've been false?

Comment: The empty set is NOT an element of $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hm, I think I have a wrong idea of the empty set.

Comment: @Cara It is the set containing no elements.  So, the set of all students in my Topology class is well-defined, and the subset of them that are also Fields medalists is well-defined, too.  The latter just happens to be empty (so far).

Comment: @Cara You have the right idea of the emptyset, but the wrong idea of "element of:" $X\subseteq Y$ does **not** imply that $X\in Y$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\mathbb Z\setminus\mathbb Q=\emptyset$ and $\emptyset\subset\mathbb N$.

Comment: Why does it say "hint"? It's a complete answer. Granted, there's no explanation as to *why* this is the case, but it's definitely not "a hint".

Comment: While I agree that this is a complete answer, what the OP wrote made me think that he or her would not see as obvious the statement that $\mathbb Z\setminus\mathbb Q=\emptyset$ and that therefore that person would have to make some effort in order to understand it.